# Error en Java: "Variable might not have been initialized"

Tags: java

[image]

Aqui lo que hago es llamar a la clase "Aplicacion" para crear una tabla, en el error de la "c" me dice que no ha sido inicializada, ¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Por favor, no publiques un pantallazo de tu código, publica el código mismo.

Comment: Intentaré publicar el código la próxima vez, me verán preguntando seguido.

Comment: Eso es cierto c sólo está declarada, más NO INICIALIZADA qué es lo que te dice el IDE.. intenta cambiando por app, ya qué app es tu instancia INICIALIZADA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que crear una instancia de esa clase mediante el comando `new` con todos sus parámetros tal y como has hecho con `app`:

```
Aplicacion c = new Aplicacion(parámetros);
```

De hecho, deberías usar `app` en vez de `c` para acceder a los métodos de tu clase ya que ya la tienes inicializada y de esta manera evitas duplicar variables.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda <3, ya es un peso menos ese error.

Comment: @MiṕsTrash. De nada! Es un placer haberte ayudado :)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que inicializar tu variable, tienes declarado el y la variable:

```
Aplicacion c;
```

`Aplicacion` en realidad es una clase que tiene que recibir 6 parámetros, puedes verlo en la inicialización de `app` :

```
Aplicacion app = new Applicacion( , , , , , );
```

Por lo tanto para `c` tendrías que realizar lo mismo:

```
Aplicacion c = new Applicacion( , , , , , );
```

---

Revisa tu aplicación porque podrías no necesitar crear otra instancia de la clase `Aplicacion` y usar la ya creada que es `app`.