# Error"variable numAlum might not have been initialized"

Tags: java

Me pidieron de tarea realizar este programa pero al intentar proteger con un try catch una variable que se ocupa en un objeto me marca error y quisiera ver si hay una forma de aplicar el try catch ya que es un requisito de la tarea que se aplique el try catch[image]

Comment: Nunca insertes imágenes con tu código ya que no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la borres para pegar el código completo en su lugar. Para más información puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). De igual forma agrega en el cuerpo del mensaje exactamente dónde obtienes el error y podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Entiendo, muchisimas gracias Roberto.

Comment: Inicia la variable en 0 fuera del try catch
Como dijo el compa de arriba

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error en Java: "Variable might not have been initialized"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32418/error-en-java-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized)

Answer (score 0):

La solución es declarar la varianle `numAlum` fuera del bloque `try-catch`, e inicializar la variable en `0`.

Por ejemplo:

```
...variables

int numAlumno = 0;

...Variables

try{
    numAlumno = // aca pones la logica del numero
}catch (Excepcion ex){
    //codigo de la exepcion
}finally { //codigo finally }

Alunmos [numAlumno];

//Mas código
```